# Firebase Authentication and Websockets

Tags: firebase, websocket, firebase-authentication

I am working on a Flutter app that uses Firebase for authentication. I am using `firebase_auth` package to achieve that. It is working fine. Majority of my Flutter application will be based on Websockets for which I am using `web_socket_channel` package.

Since websockets don't support sending custom headers and such, I cannot send idToken of the currently logged in user when the Websockets connection is established. So I must create a session on server-side to store the idToken. Since `firebase_auth` is all client-side, I must sign user in using Firebase Admin SDK. If I do that, I lose the functionality of refreshing the idToken when it expires. I can still refresh the idToken but that kinds of defeats the whole purpose of using `firebase_auth` package which provides all these functionality out of the box.

How do I achieve best of both worlds where I can still use `firebase_auth` package for all the Authentication purpose and still maintain a session on server-side with the correct idToken for the user even if it refreshes.

If I am going about it all wrong way, please point me in the right direction. I am not looking for code. I am looking for general direction as I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot send idToken of the currently logged in user when the Websockets connection is established.

Actually, you can.  Just send it as part of a data payload on that websocket like anything else you would send to the server.  A websocket enables bi-directional communication between the entities on either side, and they are free to implement their own messaging protocol over that socket.

> Since firebase_auth is all client-side, I must sign user in using Firebase Admin SDK.

That's not possible.  Firebase Admin doesn't sign in users.  Firebase Admin is *stateless* and operates only with existing stored data.  Only frontends can sign in a user.  After sign-in, the frontend should send the ID token to the backend (as I just mentioned) in order for it to use Firebase Admin to [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and operate on the user's behalf.

> If I do that, I lose the functionality of refreshing the idToken when it expires.

This is one big reason why the sign-in is managed on the frontend.  You should instruct your frontend to listen to ID token changes, and send each new token to the backend for verification.

> How do I achieve best of both worlds ... and still maintain a session on server-side with the correct idToken for the user even if it refreshes.

As above, use the websocket to enable the frontend to send token updates to the backend.

Comment: so like if it were a chat message, i should send the idToken in the payload like `{idToken: "xxxxx", topic: "chat", message: "hello world"}` and then validate that on the server using Firebase-Admin-SDK?

Comment: I would instead send a separate data frame just after opening the socket with just the ID token, since that will likely be valid across multiple chat message. Then listen for ID token changes in the Flutter app, and if you receive a new token, send that to the server. On the server, associate the ID token with the web socket connection - and clear it out when the socket closes and times out. This pretty much what the Firebase Realtime Database does for *its* web socket protocol.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: In that case, I will have to store it in a session somewhere to identify which idToken belongs to which socket connection. Is there something that is unique to websockets that I can use as a Key to do that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: The reason i would like to use something from websocets as a key so that I can clear out the list of connected websockets when the websocet disconnects and also not leave expired idToken sessions hanging unless there is a way to get the old idToken when the auth state changes.

Comment: A websocket typically represents a user session anyway.  A user should need no more than one connection at a time.  Also, I would find it hard to believe that two or more users would somehow use the same connection.  One websocket, one user, one ID token (refreshed as needed).